# Download Json from url

Tags: android, http, url, download

I'm trying to download a file (Json) from a server, but for some reason my code doesn't work.
I gave the application internet permission in manifest, the url is correct (at least it works when i simply copy&paste it to browser)...
Can someone see whats the problem here? I surrounded the download with a try/catch, but it always throws an exception.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

```
private String downloadFile() throws IOException {
    String toReturn = "";
    URL url = new URL(urlDefault + itemToSearch);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Code: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toReturn += line;
        }

        br.close();
        is.close();
        conn.disconnect();

    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("HTTP response: " + responseCode);
    }
    return toReturn;
```

}

Comment: What's the exception it's throwing?

Comment: It seems like the app isn't even getting to the if/else decision. All i get in the logcat are the "catch" statements i defined in the try/catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what's going on without more details on the exception, but my guess is that you are trying to access a network on the UI thread. Search for how to use and AsyncTask in order to do this. It'll looks something like this:

```
public class downloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        yourCodeHere
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's true, i'm working on the ui-thread. Is it never a good idea to download anything without using another thread/asyncTask?

Comment: Not only is it not a good idea, it's not allowed. Any attempt at network access from the UI thread will throw an exception. This is because it is very easy for network calls to get hung up and delay the main thread from responding. If that happens then your app will likely crash with an ANR error.